# Check serde_json Value for value with key sets of arbitrary depth or add if null Rust

Tags: rust

With something like the `vec` below Id like to add arbitrary depth to a json object.

```
let set = vec![vec!["123","apple","orange","999"],vec!["1234","apple"],vec!["12345","apple","orange"]];
```

Once created the above would look something like:

```
{"123":{"apple":{"orange":"999"}}, "1234":"apple", "12345":{"apple":"orange"}}
```

Ive tried recursion, the issue Im running into is that Im having trouble reasoning through it. The wall Ive hit is how do I refer up the chain of values?

Is there a method Im missing here? Surely Im not the only person whos wanted to do this...

I would prefer if at all possible not writing something cumbersome that takes the length of a key set `vec` and matches creating the nesting ex.:

```
match keys.len() {
    2 => json_obj[keys[0]] = json!(keys[1]),
    3 => json_obj[keys[0]][keys[1]] = json!(keys[2]),
    4 => json_obj[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = json!(keys[3]),
     ...
    _=> ()
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with iteration -- each loop you walk deeper into the structure, and further into the iterator, but the trick is that each step you need to know if there are more elements beyond the final one because the final element needs to be a string instead of an object.  We'll do this using a `match` construct that matches on the next two items in the sequence at once.

We can further generify the function to take "anything that can be turned into an iterator that produces items from which we can obtain a `&str`".  This will accept both an iterator of `String` or an iterator of `&str`, for example, or even directly a `Vec` of either.

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use serde_json::Value;

fn set_path(
    mut obj: &mut Value,
    path: impl IntoIterator<Item=impl Borrow<str>>
) {
    let mut path = path.into_iter();
    
    // Start with nothing in "a" and the first item in "b".
    let mut a;
    let mut b = path.next();
    
    loop {
        // Shift "b" down into "a" and put the next item into "b".
        a = b;
        b = path.next();
        
        // Move "a" but borrow "b" because we will use it on the next iteration.
        match (a, &b) {
            (Some(key), Some(_)) => {
                // This level is an object, rebind deeper.
                obj = &mut obj[key.borrow()];
            }
            
            (Some(s), None) => {
                // This is the final string in the sequence.
                *obj = Value::String(s.borrow().to_owned());
                break;
            }
            
            // We were given an empty iterator.
            (None, _) => { break; }
        }
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b1fa445b88768c7547523073dab4ccca))